# Cold weather chain lube?

Tags: maintenance, chain, winter

My [Rock N Roll Gold](http://www.rocklube.com/) bike lube seems to get solid or gelatenous when stored on my unheated, but enclosed porch at colder temperatures.  Is a chain lubricated with this product still going to be sufficiently lubricated when riding in freezing (below 0c or 32f) temperatures?  Should I find a different cold weather alternative?

Comment: I do assume I should keep it at a temp where it is totally liquid (and shake it) before applying the lube, especially since the PTFE and oil seem to separate when standing, and when it solidifies it sets in distinct layers.

Comment: A PTFE lube consists of PTFE particles and a "vehicle".  The vehicle is unimportant as a lubricant, it's the PTFE that does the job.  So shouldn't be a problem, so long as the stuff's fluid when you apply it.  But most other lubes will work fine too.

Comment: I add this as a comment since it doesn't directly answer your question. I happily use White Lightning lube - Epic in summer and Wet in winter. The wet has definitely been quite viscous over the last few months (when I've ridden sub-zero) but is definitely doing its job.

Comment: @PeteH - Yeah, I'd generally recommend a "wet" lube for winter, so long as conditions aren't dusty.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a regional thing, but here in Germany, many are happy with [Ballistol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistol) applied as aerosol and not changed during the seasons.

From a material science perspective, its viscosity is very low and has little temeprature dependence. It is also said that it is environmently friendly, to the extend that you can use it on pets, which I never tried as I found chains on my bike much more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Before applying the lubricant you need to warm it to liquify and fully mix it.  After application, if the weather is cold and the oil on and in your chain turns to grease, it is still an excellent lubricant.

Comment: Yeah, the best chain lube is the wax that comes on the chain from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how far below freezing you are riding.  In close to freezing temperatures, where slush and muck are an issue, a wet lube offers better protection despite it's increased viscosity and resistance.  At colder temperatures where slush is no longer an issue (15F/-10C) you should consider a dry lube.  It will offer less resistance while riding and provide an adequate level of protection for those conditions.